# In Nodejs Can I Change token dynamically like req.cookies."Dynamic token Name"

Tags: node.js, express

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const Admin = require('../models/admin');
const auth = (cookieName) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(ckname);
    try {
      const token = req.cookies.JwtAdm; **// Note I want to Change Cookie Name 
//Dynamically So I can Access diffrent cookie like req.cookies.cookieName;**


      const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

      const rootUser = await Admin.findOne({ _id: verifyToken.id });

      if (!rootUser) {
        throw new Error('User Not Found');
      }

      req.rootUser = rootUser;

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).send('Unauthorized User : invalid Token');
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};

module.exports = auth;
```

I want to Change Cookie Name Dynamically So I can Access diffrent cookie like req.cookies.cookieName. I tried by passing cookie name in parameter it is accessable in code but not working with req.cookies.cookieName

Comment: Did you try to access using req.cookies[cookieName]?

Comment: No. didn't try this.

Comment: why does admin need different cookie names? store role alongside id in the token, do a check on if(verifyToken.role === 'admin') // do await Admin.findOne else do User.findOne

Comment: No actually I'm want to use this code for different users also so I want to access different cookies as per user.

Comment: If you access using the syntax req.cookies.cookieName you cant change the key of accessing object, so you access the key "cookieName". If you want to access a object using a key in a variable, you should use the req.cookies[cookieName]. This approach will get the content on cookieName and access the value from object from that key OR return undefined if the key does not exists.

Comment: Okey thanks Erme Schultz and Lawrence Cherone for logic.